# LLVM C API. How to determine if a LLVMValueRef is of integer or pointer type?

Tags: c, llvm

I am writing some C code using the LLVM C api.  I need to check if an instruction value is of type `int` or is a pointer.  What I have tried to do is use `LLVMTypeOf(LLVMValueRef val)` and just see if it equals ALL of the different types of `int`:  `LLVMInt1Type()`, `LLVMInt8Type()`, `LLVMInt16Type()`, etc.  I did not know how to figure out if it is a pointer type or not though and I think the method I was using to see if it was a integer is not working either.

Here is the API I have been referencing:
http://llvm.org/doxygen/modules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C API is very limited.

I think you have to use C++ API or wrap the C++ API to C API by yourself.

For example,

```
extern "C" int LLVMTypeIsPointerTy(LLVMTypeRef ty){
      return ((llvm::Type*)ty)->isPointerTy();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In c you can use LLVMGetTypeKind and LLVMTypeOf to determine what type it is.

For integer type, you can check with:

```
if(LLVMGetTypeKind(LLVMTypeOf(LLVMValueRef val))==LLVMIntegerTypeKind)
```

For pointer type, you can check with:

```
if(LLVMGetTypeKind(LLVMTypeOf(LLVMValueRef val))==LLVMPointerTypeKind)
```

Enum reference: [LLVMTypeKind](http://llvm.org/doxygen/group__LLVMCCoreTypes.html#ga2da643b0ebe215106a07c8e03f3ad8d8)